# Pandas pivot table to visual

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

[image]

I have used only plot and a bit of arithmetic to plot the following data frame. So for each Fcode, I plotted it as a bar plot to give the percentage. But I am not happy with the image I am getting is there any other way to plot it? Where the percentage number etc is more prominent and visible.

I want to use seaborn to plot the same, I hoping for a better visual. Please help with the code.

```
  FCode      2017      2018   2019      2020     2021
3   HCPL1     2          85     207      190.    324
0   HCPL2   431          591    724      537     1025
2   HCPL3   59           202    372      422     679
1   HCPL4   188          201    282      322     557
```

My code goes as follows, somehow I can't add the picture here.

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (25,10)

Test.plot(
    x = 'FunderCode',
    kind = 'barh',
    stacked = True,
    title = 'Stacked Bar Graph',
    mark_right = True)

Test_total = Test["Count_2017"] + Test["Count_2018"] +Test["Count_2019"] + Test["Count_2020"]+ Test["Count_2021"]
Test_rel = Test[Test.columns[1:]].div(Test_total, 0) * 100
  
for n in Test_rel:
    for i, (cs, ab, pc) in enumerate(zip(Test.iloc[:, 1:].cumsum(1)[n], 
                                         Test[n], Test_rel[n])):
        plt.text(cs - ab / 2, i, str(np.round(pc, 1)) + '%', 
                 va = 'center', ha = 'center', rotation = 20, fontsize = 8)
```

Comment: What "*I am not happy with the image I am getting*" mean? You will need to be more specific on what you want changed

Comment: For the bar plot for HCPL1, the percentage is not showing properly. The numerical writing can be enhanced?

Comment: Plotting using SNS library might be helpful.

Comment: I just see your deleted question, what is expected output from `group_df[group_df[ 'FunderCode'] == {H2 , H3}]` ? Do you need `group_df[group_df[ 'FunderCode'].apply(lambda x: x == {H2 , H3})]` ?